# Implementing Dynamic Partitions instead AB systems

Tags: partitions

Is there an easy way to implement dynamic partitions for the oneplus 7 or any other phone built in with AB partitions system
I want to support super.img to be able to test CGI images without the need for full wipe

Comment: what is full wipe? formatting userdata is always required between different ROMs, unrelated to partitioning scheme